# Create cache from object type through annotations

Tags: spring, spring-cache, ignite

So,

I'm trying to convert our existing caching (ehcache) to ignite cache, and migrating to spring annotations.  I'm running into some difficulty making the annotations work the same as our existing caches though - our existing caches are created automagically whenever we cache something of a new class, and the new cache has the same name as the object's class.

All the current cache logic (along with most of the normal CRUD operation logic) is in an abstract class that's extended for all our persistent objects.  In researching the spring annotations, though, it seems like I need to define the cache name on the method - which obviously doesn't work for the abstract class, unless I want all our objects to be in the same cache (possible but definitely not ideal).  Ideally I'd specify the cache name as "#this.class.toString", but SPEL isn't allowed in the cache name, like it is in the key.

It seems like the only way to resolve the cache dynamically is by creating your own cache resolver, but for some reason IgniteCache doesn't extend springframework Cache, but javax Cache, and the cache resolver has to return the former.  So I'm not even clear how Ignite cache works with spring annotations at all?

This seems like a pretty straightforward use case to me, so it seems weird that spring annotations force me to provide an explicit name on the method, when I'd assume most applications of any significant size are abstracting their persistence methods, and I feel like I must have missed some crucial documentation, but I sure can't find it.  Is there a way to specify the name of the cache on the concrete implementation, but keep the caching annotation on the abstract methods?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you use Spring annotation with EhCache? If yes, how did it work? If no, what is the reason for using them in the first place? Why not use Ignite APIs directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is quite dense and it's not very clear what you're trying to do. What is "your existing caching" for a start? You need some way to flag the places where you actually cache things I guess. I assume you already understood you need to put a cache annotation there.

As for automatically creating the cache, I wouldn't switch to a different caching system *and* trying to implement that. Try to migrate first to the cache annotations with your existing cache infrastructure and then migrate to ignite.

Let's pretend you do both still. You are right `CacheResolver` is the way to go and it can adapt to either a regular `org.springframework.cache.Cache` or a `javax.cache.Cache`. Once you have a setup that works, I'd do the following:

- In your `CacheResolver` implementation, inject the cache manager that has been configured
- Based on the method call, figure out the cache name to use (get the return type of the method, extract the FQN)
- Check if the cache manager has such cache. If it does, return that. If it doesn't create a new cache and add it and then return that

If you're using `JCacheCacheManager`, you can invoke `addCache` to create a new cache and then wrap the result in `JCacheCache` to comply with the signature of `CacheResolver`.

Last note: automatically creating the cache based on the FQN seems a bit fragile to me, especially if you have sub-classes. You need a bit of control on the caches you create and the settings you apply to them (expiration, size, etc).